# Ejecutar archivo .bat sin click derecho para ejecutar como administrador

Tags: windows, batch, msdos

Estoy ejecutando un archivo .bat, sucede que para ejecutarlo debo darle click derecho y "Ejecutar como Administrador", estoy buscando la manera de ejecutar el bat sin tener que hacer esto, sino que en el mismo bat se eleven los permisos del usuario a Administrador. 
Esto es debido a que en el bat hay comandos que hacen configuraciones en el sistema como agregar un host en el archivo Hosts de system32.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no versa sobre programación ni sobre ningún otro tema de los permitidos, tal y como se consensuó en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/19610)

Answer (score 1):

Da Clic Derecho->Propiedades->Acceso Directo->Opciones Avanzadas->Chequeas la pestaña de Ejecutar como administrador y guardar todo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]